# Error using mod_jk in apache: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_version

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

We just recently installed a new RHEL7 server.  Inside of this server, we have a bunch of vhosts, and inside the vhosts there is a line that looks like this -

```
JkMount /rules_engine/rulesApi/rules/* rulesEngine
JkMount /api/* rulesEngine
JkMount /rules_editor/* rulesEngine
```

So in order to handle this, we use mod_jk inside of our apache configuration.  However, when I try to start apache, I get the following error -

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_version
```

The mod_jk.conf file is inside of /etc/httpd/conf.d, and it looks like this -

```
LoadModule jk_module /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
Change to WARN or ERROR for Prod
JkLogLevel info
JkShmFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkMount /rulesApi/rules/* rulesEngine
JkMount /api/* rulesEngine
JkMount /* rulesEditor
JkMount /rules_editor/* rulesEditor
```

Any ideas as to what that error means, and how I can get apache to start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK,The error usually occurs if using mismatch version of mod_jk with apache. The RHEL 7 uses Apache/2.4.6.So see if you are using the supported/compatible version of mod_jk or not. I'm not sure but in my knowledge mod_jk is not supported/compatible with this default version of apache in RHEL 7. So,build the community version of apache and use the mod_jk from there.